# how to make pandas' read_excel parameter "nrows" dynamic

Tags: python, pandas

I have a excel file, which consists the Weekly Application login report from two regions.
it has columns like interval ( 03-13-2021 00:00 - 03-19-2021 22:00), Average time it took to login.

Generally, this report has 167 rows for AMR region and 167 row for EME region. both of these are placed in same sheet. There is gap of 23 rows between the two regions data.

I am using this to extract the data

```
AMR_Data = pd.read_excel(element, skiprows=38, nrows=167)
EME_Data = pd.read_excel(element, skiprows=228, nrows=167)
```

The thing is sometimes due to maintenance activity, data are missing. hence this `nrows=167` is not constant every time. How can i define nrows property to adjust itself based on the data.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jekeJ.png)

Comment: Personally, I’d seriously investigate (with the provider) the possibility of converting the source data to a *flat* CSV format, with an additional column for region.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to extract it. I am using the approach to find the first Empty cells for all the columns in DataFrame. and then do the Math to calculate the other region data.

```
first_empty_row = df[df.isnull().all(axis=1) == True].index.tolist()[0]

AMR_Data = df.loc[0:first_row_with_all_NaN-1]
EME_Data = df.loc[first_row_with_all_NaN + 23 : ]
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two solutions I can think of here:

1. Ask the user for input telling how many rows are in each section. This is probably the easiest to code, but requires user interaction.
2. Read the Excel data and detect the number of rows. This is a bit more difficult. And since you are reading the data manually, you probably shouldn't use `pandas.read_excel()`. What I have in mind here is that you read each row one at a time until you reach a blank row. Then you know the next set of data starts. You can use a library like `openpyxl` to help here.